# Delphi mobile menu

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to make a scrollable menu of text items on mobile (iOS and Android) with Delphi 10.2.3.

I've added a TListView and put labels on it. They won't scroll at runtime.

I've added a TVertScrollBox and put labels on it. They won't scroll at runtime.

Am I missing something about scrolling components?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I've never seen such a problem. I would think Emba/SO would be flooded with complaints if there was a bug of this nature. Perhaps the problem is in your code which we cannot see?

Comment: If the labels in the TVertScrollBox have HitTest set to True, the scrollbox will not scroll since the OnClick of the labels will fire if the user touches them

Comment: Actually the TVertScrollBox does allow scrolling even though the labels have HitTest set to True. I had to call BringToFront before it would work in my code.

It's the TListView that fails to scroll with labels with HitTest True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While TListView still fails to scroll with TLabels on it, TVertScrollBox does scroll when it is full of TLabels with their HitTest property set to True. Problem solved.